# Where is the source code for bulma's `pagination-previous`?

Tags: css, vue.js, bulma

There seem to only be references to the class in the repo here: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pagination-previous&type=

I'm curious about how the actual class is defined but I'm not sure how to trace the source code. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to Bulma/sass/components/pagination.sass

[pagination.sass](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/components/pagination.sass)

Comment: ah I just realized I glossed over this file because I wasn't familiar with how to read sass files

Thanks!